# Combine a default parameter value with validation via the ValidateScript attribute

Tags: validation, powershell, default-value

I have the following PowerShell code to validate user input as a path, if the user didn't enter anything, I am attempting to assign a default value to them. However when I run this, the `$filePath` variable does not gets assigned any value.

Is there anyway I can change this to have it assigned a default value while the validation is going on?

**Code below:**

```
function validatePath {
  Param
  (
      [ValidateScript({
        If ($_ -eq "" -or $_ -eq [String]::Empty) {
            $_ = "C:\Install"
            $True
        }
        ElseIf ($_ -match "^([a-z]:\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d])*)") {
            $True
        } 
        Else {
            Write-Host "Please enter a valid path,$_ is not a valid path."
            Write-debug $_.Exception
        }
      })]
      [string]$filePath = "C:\Install"
  )
  Process
  {
      Write-Host "The path is "$filePath
  }
}

validatePath -filePath $args[0]
```

Comment: What about using existing `Test-Path` in an if clause?

Comment: Pertinent: https://powershell.org/2013/05/01/why-doesnt-my-validatescript-work-correctly/. ValidateScript is only supposed to return true or false. If nothing is provided the default should be used in its place. The default will never be checked against the script though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could drop the validate script and instead do this in a Begin block:

```
Begin{
    If ($filepath -eq "") {
        $filepath = "C:\Install"
    }
    ElseIf ($filepath -notmatch "^([a-z]:\\(?:[-\\w\\.\\d])*)") {
        Write-Error "Please enter a valid path,$filepath is not a valid path."
    }
}
Process{
```

Comment: Works great, I always thought I would have just wrote a straight if/else function to do validating since I also need the default value mixed in there, this helps.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer first discusses the **correct use of the `ValidateScript` attribute**.

The unrelated **default-value issue** is discussed afterward, followed by an optional section on **parameter splatting**.</sup>

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt) provides good pointers in his comment on the question:

- **A `ValidateScript` script block should output a *Boolean only*.**
  That Boolean tells PowerShell whether the parameter value is considered valid or not, and *it* takes action accordingly.

  - Notably, the script block is *not* meant to:

    - assign to the parameter variable directly
    - contain any other output statements such as `Write-Host` (which you shouldn't use to report *errors* anyway).
  - **If the script block outputs (effective) `$False` *or* the script block throws an *exception*,** PowerShell:

    - **aborts invocation** of the function
    - reports a ***non-terminating* error**
  - If the script block outputs `$False`, you get **a generic error message that includes the *literal contents* of your script block** (excluding the enclosing `{` and `}`) - which may be **too technical for end users**.

    - **PowerShell *Core*** introduced an **[optional `ErrorMessage = "..."` field](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/2728)** for both the `ValidateScript` and `ValidatePattern` attributes; e.g.,
      `[ValidateScript({ $_ % 2 -eq 0 }, ErrorMessage = "{0} is not an even number.")]`
    - **In *Windows* Powershell**, it is advisable to *throw an exception* with a user-friendly error message**, in which case PowerShell includes the exception text in its error message.
- **A parameter's *default value* is by design *not* checked against the validation script** - you as the function creator assume the responsibility of defaulting to a value that is valid - see [this blog post](https://powershell.org/2013/05/01/why-doesnt-my-validatescript-work-correctly/).

Applied to your example:

<sup>Note that I'm using `'^[a-z]:\\[-\w\d\\]*$'` as the regex, because that's what I think you actually meant to use.</sup>

```
function validatePath {
  Param
  (
    [ValidateScript({
      if ($_ -match '^[a-z]:\\[-.\w\d\\]*$') { return $True }
      Throw "'$_' is not a valid local path." 
    })]
    [string] $filePath = "C:\Install"
  )
  Process
  {
    "The path is: $filePath"
  }
}
```

Now all 3 invocation scenarios should work as intended:

```
> validatePath                          # use default value
The path is: C:\Install

> validatePath -filePath C:\MyInstall   # valid path
The path is: C:\MyInstall

> validatePath -filePath NotAFullPath   # invalid path -> error with custom message
validatePath : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'filePath'.
'NotAFullPath' is not a valid local path.
At line:1 char:24
+ validatePath -filePath NotAFullPath   # invalid path
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [validatePath], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,validatePath
```

---

#### Why your default parameter value didn't take effect:

This issue is **unrelated to validation**, and stems from the fact that you're passing `$args[0]` in your `validatePath` invocation:

- If the script itself received no arguments, **`$args[0]`** is `$null`, but it is **still being passed as an *explicit value***, so it binds to parameter `$filePath` by coercion to an *empty string*.
- **Since an explicit parameter value was passed, the default value wasn't used**, and `$filePath` ended up containing the empty string.

Since this is how parameter binding works in PowerShell, I suggest *not* trying to work around it *inside your function*, but to instead **fix the problem *on invocation***:

```
if ([string] $args[0]) { # only true if $args[0] is neither $null nor the empty string
  validatePath -filePath $args[0]
} else {
  validatePath
}
```

<sup>Note that it's usually preferable to declare your parameters explicitly rather than using `$args`.</sup>

---

#### Optional reading: using *splatting* to (selectively) pass arguments through to another command:

As an alternative to using two separate invocations in the conditional above, consider using [parameter splatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), which allows you to pass multiple parameters using a single collection variable, prefixed with `@`:

- an *array* that represents multiple *positional* parameters.
- more commonly and more robustly, a *hashtable* that represents multiple *named* parameters.

This allows you to dynamically build the collection of parameters ahead of time, and the pass the collection as a whole to a *single* invocation of the target command.

A quick and dirty workaround in your case would be to use **splatting with *all* parameters**, i.e. to pass `$args` through (note the `@` sigil instead of `$`):

```
validatePath @args
```

This would simply pass all arguments, *if any*, passed to the script through to `validatePath` as if they had been specified separately; if no argument is passed to the script, nothing is passed through, and the `-filePath` default value inside `validatePath` *does* take effect.

**Parameter-individual splatting** is another option, which is **a robust technique for passing select parameters through to another command**:

```
# Define a hashtable to hold the parameters, if any, to pass through
# to validatePath() via splatting.
$htPassthruParams = @{}

# If the first script argument is neither $null nor the empty string,
# add a hashtable entry for it that will bind to the -filePath parameter.
if ([string] $args[0]) { $htPassthruParams.Add('filePath', $args[0]) }

# Pass the hashtable with `@`, the splatting operator, to validatePath()
validatePath @htPassthruParams
```

If you **declare your script with explicit parameters** as well (using its own `param(...)` block), the approach can be generalized by **using the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` dictionary to determine if a parameter was *bound***, which obviates the need to check for a specific value:

```
# Define a hashtable to hold the parameters, if any, to pass through
# to validatePath() via splatting.
$htPassthruParams = @{}

# Using a list of parameters, pass their values through only if they are 
# *bound*, i.e., only if they received values when the enclosing script/function
# itself was called.
# Assume that the enclosing script declared a -filePath parameter too.
foreach($paramName in , 'filePath') {   
  if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey($paramName)) { 
    $htPassthruParams.Add($paramName, $PSBoundParameters[$paramName]) 
  }
}

# Pass the hashtable with `@`, the splatting operator, to validatePath()
validatePath @htPassthruParams
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. If the user don't enter any positional argument, how can I assign my $args default values? such as that $arg[0] to $arg[3] all have defaults that I want them to be assigned?

Comment: Note that all arguments are positional by default, unless you explicitly deactivate this feature. Don't use `$args`, declare your parameters explicitly: e.g., `param($arg1='default1', $arg2='default2', $arg3='default3')` defines 3 implicitly positional parameters and their default values (works in functions as well as scripts). If you still have questions, please _post a new question_ (and feel free to let me know here).